# Sorting only considers the first digit when the table is sorted with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table with total points. I have javascript which sorts the table based on the total but it says: if points are 1,25,6,4 - sorting considers only the first digit. So it sorts by 1,25,4,6.

W1, W2, W3 ...columns are dynamically created, and also the rows.

Please help

---

```js
const sortTotal = () => {
  const tbl = [...document.getElementsByClassName("fl-table")][0];
  const tbody = [...tbl.tBodies][0];
  const oObjects = [];

  [...tbody.rows].forEach(row => {
    const cells = [...row.cells];
    const obj = [...row.cells].map(cell => {
      return cell.innerHTML;
    });
    oObjects.push(obj);
  });

  oObjects.sort((a, b) => a[a.length - 1] > b[b.length - 1] ? 1 : -1);

  [...tbody.rows].forEach((row, i) => {
    [...row.cells].forEach((cell, j) => {
      cell.innerHTML = oObjects[i][j];
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<button onClick="sortTotal()">
  Sort</button>
</button>
<table class="fl-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Player</th>
      <th>Player Name</th>
      <th>W1</th>
      <th>W2</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="agl-profile-img-new"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70C/O https://placeholder.com/"></td>
      <td>Heather Rankin</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="agl-profile-img-new"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70C/O https://placeholder.com/"></td>
      <td>Stephen Puopolo</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="agl-profile-img-new"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70C/O https://placeholder.com/"></td>
      <td>Latheesh V M V</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Comment: `oObjects.sort((a, b) => a[a.length - 1] > b[b.length - 1] ? 1 : -1);` This looks wrong

Comment: @bassxzero it seems to work if the digit count is 1 for total points, otherwise, it fails.

Comment: Try `oObjects.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a) > parseInt(b) ? 1 : -1);`

Comment: @bassxzero sorry it gives the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting the string numbers to actual numbers,

```
oObjects.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a[a.length - 1]) - parseInt(b[b.length - 1]));
```

Notice the parseInt method and also notice that I have removed the ternary operator. There is a reason for that. The sort method expect actually any of the three following output.

**1: a should come after b**

**0: the order should not change**

**-1: a should come before b**

You can read more about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```js
const sortTotal = () => {
  const tbl = [...document.getElementsByClassName("fl-table")][0];
  const tbody = [...tbl.tBodies][0];
  const oObjects = [];

  [...tbody.rows].forEach(row => {
    const cells = [...row.cells];
    const obj = [...row.cells].map(cell => {
      return cell.innerHTML;
    });
    oObjects.push(obj);
  });

  oObjects.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a[a.length - 1]) - parseInt(b[b.length - 1]));

  [...tbody.rows].forEach((row, i) => {
    [...row.cells].forEach((cell, j) => {
      cell.innerHTML = oObjects[i][j];
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<button onClick="sortTotal()">
  Sort</button>
</button>
<table class="fl-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Player</th>
      <th>Player Name</th>
      <th>W1</th>
      <th>W2</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="agl-profile-img-new"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70C/O https://placeholder.com/"></td>
      <td>Heather Rankin</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="agl-profile-img-new"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70C/O https://placeholder.com/"></td>
      <td>Stephen Puopolo</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="agl-profile-img-new"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70C/O https://placeholder.com/"></td>
      <td>Latheesh V M V</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>26</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you seems to work. The order seems to be reversed how that can be fixed pls?

Comment: You can reverse this part `parseInt(a[a.length - 1]) - parseInt(b[b.length - 1])` to `parseInt(b[b.length - 1]) - parseInt(a[a.length - 1]) `

Comment: thank you. It works. What happens if two numbers are same? How does it order in that case?

Comment: It will keep the current order.

Comment: I mean what order does it decide? 2 and 2 ? Does it order by name or something?

Comment: No it will not consider anything else, if a.total === b.total then it will not swap there places. It will not compare a.name and b.name unless you specify.

Comment: It is currently not swapping places, earlier it used to swap. Is there any way to make it work like that please?

Comment: Yeah in that case just use your old ternary logic with parseInt() part i.e. `parseInt(a[a.length - 1]) > parseInt(b[b.length - 1]) ? 1 : -1`

Comment: it seems to do nothing when I change it to :  `oObjects.sort((a, b) => parseInt(b[b.length - 1]) > parseInt(a[a.length - 1])); `

Comment: oh okay sorry got it

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.I am total new to it :)